# data.table "losing" factor levels under certain conditions

Tags: r, data.table

Using the `data.table` package, I am working with the following data frame, produced with `reproduce(df`

```
    outRes vars ts_length   BIAS
1       1t   sd         0 -0.046
2       1t   sd         3 -0.105 
3       1t   sd         6 -0.249
4       1t   sd         1 -0.024
5       1t   sd         1  1.246
6       1t   sd         6  0.885
7       1t   sd         1  0.280
46    day    sd         0 -0.061    
47    day    sd         3 -0.119
48    day    sd         6 -0.256
49    day    sd         1 -0.039
50    day    sd         1  1.239
51    day    sd         6  0.888
52    day    sd         1  0.253
268  month   LE         1 -0.085
269  month   LE         3 -0.147
270  month   LE         6 -0.305


df <- structure(list(outRes = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,3L, 3L, 3L), 
          .Label = c("1t", "day", "month"), class = "factor"),
           vars = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("H","LE", "sd", "sm2", "Ts2"), class = "factor"),
           ts_length = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L,4L), .Label = c("0", "1", "3", "6"), class = "factor"), 
           BIAS = c(-0.046,-0.105, -0.249, -0.024, 1.246, 0.885, 0.28, -0.085, -0.147,-0.305)), 
          .Names = c("outRes", "vars", "ts_length", "BIAS"), class = "data.frame",
           row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L,7L, 268L, 269L, 270L))
```

Firstly, I need to find the lowest value in `df$BIAS` per group of `df$vars` and `df$outRes`. Using the example above, `outRes=1t` and `vars = sd`, the smallest BIAS is -0.024 so I need to print `ts_length` = "1"; for `outRes = day`, I need `ts_length` = 0 for smallest `BIAS` = -0.061. Using the `data.table` package, I can output the value of `BIAS`  with

```
 dt = as.data.table(df)
 dt[,min(abs(BIAS)),by="vars,outRes"]
```

which gives me the output

```
vars outRes    V1
1:   sd     1t 0.024
2:  sm2     1t 2.615
3:  Ts2     1t 0.000
4:    H     1t 0.735
5:   LE     1t 0.018
6:   sd    day 0.039
7:  sm2    day 2.661 etc...
```

What I would like to do is also obtain the `df$ts_length` corresponding to the `V1`column. I have tried

```
setkey(dt,outRes,vars,BIAS) 
dt[J(dt[,min(abs(BIAS)),by="outRes,vars"])]
       [V1== BIAS,list(ID,ts_length,BIAS,outRes,vars)]
```

but 2 out of the 5 levels of the `$vars` disappear, giving these results:

```
   ts_length  BIAS outRes vars
1:         3 0.018     1t   LE
2:         0 2.615     1t  sm2
3:         6 0.000     1t  Ts2
4:         0 0.005    day   LE
5:         0 2.661    day  sm2
```

I am new to `data.table` and admit that I don't really understand the code itself too well so I also tried

```
setkey(dt,vars,outRes,BIAS) 
dt[J(dt[,min(abs(BIAS)),by="vars,outRes"])]
       [V1== BIAS,list(ts_length,BIAS,vars,outRes)]
```

but I only get 3 levels too. What is happening? How can I have the 5 levels of the factor `vars` rather than just 3?

Comment: a simple, reproducible example will get you an answer much quicker

Comment: Please provide input and the expected output.  I don't understand why you think you need a join.

Comment: Hi, the following function is `data.table` aware.   To help make a reproducible example, you can use   `reproduce(<your data>)` . Instructions are here: http://bit.ly/SORepro   -  [How to make a great R reproducible example](http://bit.ly/SORepro)

Comment: Following @Ricardo Saporta's suggestion, I have edited the question using the output of `reproduce`. @eddi, would you still like a reproducible example? @Roland, I have added the input and expected output. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the reproducible example. 
Try the following:

```
setkey(dt, vars, outRes)

dt[ CJ(levels(vars), levels(outRes))
  , .SD[abs(BIAS) == min(abs(BIAS))]
  , .SDcols=c("BIAS", "ts_length")
]

    vars outRes   BIAS ts_length
 1:    H     1t     NA        NA
 2:    H    day     NA        NA
 3:    H  month     NA        NA
 4:   LE     1t     NA        NA
 5:   LE    day     NA        NA
 6:   LE  month -0.085         1
 7:   sd     1t -0.024         1
 8:   sd    day     NA        NA
 9:   sd  month     NA        NA
10:  sm2     1t     NA        NA
11:  sm2    day     NA        NA
12:  sm2  month     NA        NA
13:  Ts2     1t     NA        NA
14:  Ts2    day     NA        NA
15:  Ts2  month     NA        NA
```

Comment: Why `CJ` here? Wouldn't this be sufficient? `DT[DT[, .I[which.min(abs(BIAS))], by=list(vars, outRes)]$V1]`? (and then take `abs(BIAS)` of course)

Comment: Thanks to both @Ricardo Saporta and @Arun. Both suggestions work. I admit that, as a novice in `data.table` package, I find @Ricardo Saporta's command easier to understand (for example, I don't understand what `$V1` does in @Arun's suggestion).

Comment: @SnowFrog, have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21198937/subset-data-table-using-min-condition/21199009#21199009).